# How to run QT program in linux command

Tags: linux, qt

I'm very new to linux. Actually i created a qt program using qt creator and its working fine. But i want to run the program using the linux command. I saved my created project in desktop/test folder/test1.How to execute the program , guide me...

I referred google , they suggest that to move project directory through command. But i dont know how to go the desktop and test/test1 folder.

Comment: The question is not about qt. Read how to use the shell first. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0020.php

Comment: Normally you have to create a shortcut for a shell script that you can execute from an icon.  But if you don't even know how to navigate your drive with the terminal, you've got a long way to go.  (ps:  lookup how "cd" and "ls" work.  They are your starting point)

Comment: For starter type `cd ~/Desktop/test\ folder/test1` to navigate to your project directory. You can use `ls` command to see the contents of your folder. If the project built fine then your executable should be in that directory. Type `./test1` in that directory (assuming that is the name of your target). But honestly it may not work for various reasons. You have to learn how to use the shell first as pointed out by others.